# how to add pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have posts in different custom taxonomies. I need to display posts for one taxonomy  in a page. Now I'm getting the all the posts in all taxonomies in a single page.  I have a foreach loop for taxonomy and inside the loop all the posts corresponding to that taxonomy is displaying through post method.I have never used pagination before. How can I add pagination in this case?
I am enclosing my code below

```
<div class="main">

<section class="brands-sec product-sec">
<div class="container">
<?php
$siteurl = home_url('/');
$tax = 'product';  // slug of taxonomy
$terms = get_terms($tax);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$id = $term->term_id;
$slug = $term->slug;
$description = $term->description;
$image_url = z_taxonomy_image_url( $id, NULL, TRUE ); // category image display
$link = "<a href='$siteurl?$tax=$slug' ><h1> $term->name </h1></a>";

echo '<img src="' . $image_url . '">'; ?>
    <div class="col-md-8 pull-right col-sm-10 pull-right col-xs-12 brnd prdct">

        <img src="<?php echo $image_url ; ?>" class="img-responsive pdt-logo" alt="loyd"/>

        <div class="brand-logos pdt">

        <p><?php echo $description ; ?></p>

                <h4>Product</h4>
             <?php $args = array("posts_per_page" => "-1", "product"=>$slug ,"post_type" => "products" );
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($posts as $data){
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($data ->ID) );
$custom_fonts = get_post_custom($data->ID);$custom_fonts_key=     $custom_fonts['category'];$custom_fonts_array = $custom_fonts_key[0]; ?>                    
            <div class="row mb40">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 brand-single product-single">
                    <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="allegro products"/>
                    <h5><?php echo $data->post_title; ?></h5>
                    <p><?php echo $data->post_content; ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 brand-single product-detail">
                    <ul class="products">
                    <?php 
    $attachments = new Attachments( 'my_attachments',$data->ID ); /* pass the instance name */ ?>
<?php if( $attachments->exist() ) : ?>
<?php while( $attachments->get() ) : ?>
                    <li><img src="<?php echo $attachments->url(); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="allegro products"/></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>


                </div>


            </div>
 <?php } ?>             

        </div><!--end brand-logos-->

     </div><!--end brnd-->
     <?php } ?>

</div>
```

Here product is custom taxonomy . In that there are more than one terms say loyd,Nycofee,.... In Both these terms there are more than one posts. I need to display posts in loyd in one page and ncofee in next page. How to add pagination in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You have the post_per_page to be -1

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array("posts_per_page" => "-1", "product"=>$slug ,"post_type" => "products" );
```

change it to the number you would like. and add to the end

```
'paged' => $paged
```

before Ending the PHP here

```
            </div>
 <?php } ?>             

        </div><!--end brand-logos-->
```

Add

```
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $args )); ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

---

Here is the basic pagination for wordpress

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

<!-- Start of the main loop. -->
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>

<!-- the rest of your theme's main loop -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- End of the main loop -->

<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Soruce: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination "Example Loop with Pagination"

If it still show the full list.
Try this: http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination

Comment: you can check this url http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination

Comment: this code is not working. If I have added the post_per_page as 1. Then it will shows 1 post for each terms in a single page. Means in a single page there are 1 post for 'Loyd' and 1 post is displaying under 'Nycofee' .

Comment: Try adding this above the $args `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`  try to change the post per page to 5 too

Comment: Again not working. Actually I need to add pagination not for the post. The first foreach loop displays all the terms. In each term there are any number of posts. I need to display one terms and its all posts (don't know the number of posts) in one page then next term and all its post in the next page and so on. pagination for the first loop